# Select Shadow DOM with JavaScript and/or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, polymer, shadow-dom

It seems like Chrome deprecated `/deep/` and `>>>` and `::shadow`: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120

Does anyone know if there is another way to access the Shadow DOM?

My use case is trying to figure out the style of an input. Specifically I'm trying to detect if a placeholder is being displayed or not.

I've tried `el.shadowRoot` but it returns null and the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) for it are pretty sparse.

Comment: I hope you aren't trying to do this in a cross browser sort of way.. if so I believe you are out of luck. Your best bet would be to check for a :selected state, at this time you know the placeholder will not be showing because a selection has been made. All other times it should be.

Comment: If you must style the select element or any other shadow DOM element you should hide the real select but use a fake select to manipulate the hidden dropdown's selection. This helps with accessibility. https://select2.github.io/ select2 is a widely used one that is coded well.

Comment: 1) I'm not operating on a <select>, I'm operating on an input[type="text"]. 2) :selected isn't a pseudo selector, it's :focus, and I'm using that but when you originally load the page the field is invalid. http://codepen.io/corysimmons/pen/XdmqeY?editors=1100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only access Shadow DOM of the elements created via a call to `attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )`. If it is the case then calling `shadowRoot` should work.

You cannot access Shadow DOM from user agent controls (`<input>`, `<select>`), added by the browser.

To check if a placeholder is displayed or not, I would verify if it exists and if the input value is empty or not:

```
if ( myInput.getAttribute( "placeholder" ) && !myInput.value.length )
    //the placeholder is being displayed
```

```js
myInput.oninput = function() {
  if (myInput.getAttribute("placeholder") && !myInput.value.length)
    myInput.classList.add("empty")
  else
    myInput.classList.remove("empty")
}
```

```css
 body {
   padding: 100px;
 }
 input {
   border: 2px solid;
   padding: 10px;
   outline: none;
 }
 input:valid {
   border-color: springgreen;
 }
 input:invalid {
   border-color: tomato;
 }
 input[placeholder].empty {
   border-color: darkturquoise
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" required placeholder="the placeholder" id="myInput" class="empty">
```

**Update**

Chrome and Safari support the CSS pseudo-class `:placeholder-shown` that can be used to style your element when the placeholder is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. That's what I ended up doing after all.

Answer (score 1):

If you use shady DOM (default) instead of shadow DOM, then you need to use Polymer API to access the DOM.

```
Polymer.dom(el.root)
```

AFAIK it's not decided yet if `>>>` and `::shadow` will be removed from JS. Therefore `querySelector('x >>> y')` might be supported longer. For CSS it's definitive that it will be removed.